# Abaqus python scripting - Element set created in .mdb not accessible in .odb

Tags: python, set, element, abaqus, odb

I've created a Set of elements in the rootAssembly in an .mdb file:

```
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
els_1 = a.instances['Part-1'].elements
Coh_els = els_1.getByBoundingBox(x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2) 
a.Set(elements=Coh_els, name='COHELSET-0')
```

I'm attempting to access field outputs in this element set in the .odb file:

```
coh_els = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1'].elementSets['COHELSET-0']
```

But I get 'KeyError: COHELSET-0' (the element set is not visible in the .odb model tree) so I cannot access the field output in this set.

The rest of my code works when I use an element set that is visible in the tree so I know the problem is in accessing the pre-defined element set.

Could somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by changing the line

```
coh_els = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1'].elementSets['COHELSET-0']
```

to

```
coh_els = odb.rootAssembly.elementSets['COHELSET-0']
```

Comment: Yeah, you created the set under`a`, which is `rootAssembly`